# Poor behavior/performance with context menu in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a problem with a context menu appearing within a user control structure as shown in the follwing XAML.

First, I have a user control representing a calendar. It consists of a 7x6 grid; each cell of the grid represents a date on the calendar. This XAML is a simplified version of my actual implmentation with details removed where I assume they are not relevant. Note that the calendar grid (ListView) is on a tab (not sure if that has any relevance to my problem, or the fact that this control operates inside of another level of tab in the host window).

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600" >
    <TabControl >
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Calendar" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <Grid>
                <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="7" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:CalendarCell  Updated="CalendarCell_Updated"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

Within each cell of the above grid is a user control (CalendarCell) representing a date on the calendar, as shown below. Part of the structure of this control is a ListView containing items to be displayed for a date:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CalendarCell"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThisMonthTextBrush" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TodayTextBrush" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OtherMonthTextBrush" Color="LightGray" />
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="Edit" Header="Edit This Item" Click="Edit_Click" />
            <MenuItem Name="Delete" Header="Delete This Item" Click="Delete_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border x:Name="CellBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="3">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder"  >
                            <TextBlock Padding="3" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Note}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                        </Border>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DayOfMonth" Padding="3" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Date.Day}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{Binding Path=ItemBrush}" />
        </Grid>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The problem I have with all this is in the behavior of the context menu attached to the date's ListView items. The context menu only appears sporadically... if I try a few times, or hold the right button for a few seconds, I can get the menu to appear; a quick click (as one would normally do to invoke the context menu) rarely works. When the menu does appear, it works as expected... it just requires a lot of persistence and fiddling to get it to appear.

My suspicion is that something is consuming the events before they can be delivered to the appropriate UI element, or that it may be a focus issue, but can't think of how to trace the cause of the issue.

Note that I am using data triggers to add hover feedback (which works correctly)... doesn't alter context menu behavior if I remove the data triggers, so they don't appear to be related to the problem.

By the way, this is VS2010 .NET 4 on Vista SP2.

Comment: Any errors in output window? Try CONTROL + F5 to run app without debug output and check the performance then.

Comment: Behavior is the same for debug or release build, running under debug or not. I did notice that I was getting some binding errors related to VerticalContentAlignment, but after removing all the associated setters, I still got the same behavior.

Comment: I do not think it is contextmenu itself doing something unusual. You only have two menuitems inside. It must be something else. Try to profile your app. Download a free performance profiler somewhere online and let me know whats the hot spot